# Batch - Rename subfolder

Tags: batch-file, rename, subdirectory

I'm trying to create a Batch to rename all the subfolders that have "_" in the name.
This works but only for folders under the TEST path.

How can I go to subfolders too?

Example C:\TEST\name_TMP  the result is  C:\TEST\name

Instead with C:\TEST\name\name_TMP the script doesn't work

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "SourceDir=C:\TEST\"
FOR /d %%i IN ("%SourceDir%\*") DO (
   set "FolderName=%%~nxi"
   if "!FolderName:~-4,1!"=="_" REN "%%~i" "!FolderName:~0,-4!"
)
endlocal
```

Maybe, if possible, find and remove only the _TMP part

Comment: not explicitly documented, but you can combine the `/d` (directories) switch with the `/r` (recursive) switch: `for /d /r "%sourcedir%" %%i in (*) do echo %%i`

Comment: try `echo !foldername:_TMP=!` (removing `_TMP` (case insensitive))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one works

```
cd /d e:\ && FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=_" %a in ('dir /ad /on /b /s *_TMP* |find /i "_TMP" |sort /r') do ren "%a_%b" "%~nxa"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your code with slight adjustments:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "SourceDir=C:\TEST"
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /b /s /a:d "%SourceDir%\*" ^| findstr /R "_TMP$"') DO (
   set "Folder=%%~fi"
   echo ren "%%~fi" "!Folder:_TMP=!"
)
```

Only remove `echo` once you confirmed the output is what you expect it to be.
Note, this is untested as I posted from my mobile.

Comment: It doesn't work. No changes

Comment: FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=_" %a in ('dir /ad /on /b /s *_* ^|find /i "_" ^|sort /r') do ren "%a_%b" "%~nxa" I find this solution but work only on CMD. How can I put it in a batch?

Comment: double all `%` as in `FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=_" %%a in ('dir /ad /on /b /s _ ^|find /i "_" ^|sort /r') do ren "%%a_%%b" "%%~nxa"`